# VS2010 possible to convert projects back to VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio

As you all know the VS 2010 RC is out for MSDN subcribers.

Unfortunately I guess I have the same problem as some of you, in that the company I work for wants to continue keeping our projects on VS 2008.

I would like to know if its possible for me to work with VS 21010, then later convert my projects back to VS2008?

I intend to use v3 of the framework for this particular project.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on a kind of project you use. It's absolutely impossible to convert VC++ back from 2010 since they have completely different format and no tools to rollback. However, C# and VB.NET still use the same msbuild project format as in VS2008, which will be changed in the next VS version (Dev11) and so all you need to manage C# or VB.NET project version is the ToolsVersion attribute of the Project element.

VS 2008 C# project version:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

VS 2010 C# project version:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

One of the approaches is to use both project systems simultaneously as our team does. Another one is to use targeting for different .NET frameworks in VS2010 projects. V2010 supports all previous .NET frameworks as targets farmeworks till .NET 2.0

Finally, don't be upset by using VS2008 as it's much faster and reliable.

Answer (score 19):

[I've just created a little batch file that will convert between VS2008 and VS2010 (and vice versa) at will](http://cultiv.nl/blog/2010/3/16/convert-between-vs2008-and-2010-projects,-automatically).

It rewrites the strings found at http://blogs.msdn.com/rextang/archive/2009/07/06/9819189.aspx between both versions in an automated fashion.

Comment: Bravo! This has saved me from tedium!

Comment: Few tips for folks reading.. before downgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2008 (*.sln file), remove all .NET 4.0 dll references, and unload any files referencing those dlls in the projects!  And also change the .NET version of any projects from .NET 4.0 to .NET 3.5 since 4.0 is not supported in VS 2008.  I recently converted Telerik's Rad Controls for ASP.NET AJAX VS 2010 *.sln file to VS 2008, and got it to compile, and ran into these issues ..

Comment: @sebastiaan The first link is broken, can you update it?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to keep the work projects in VS 2k8 and just convert up to VS 2k10 on your end. Of course this means you would have to manually edit back in any changes you make to the solution or project files but you would have to do that either way you go.

Perhaps it would be best if your company invested in utilities (such as SCons or CMake) that are able to generate solution/project files for as many IDE's as you need given a set of metadata so that the companies engineers can use whatever environment they are most comfortable with.

While I think there is an argument to be made for having everyone work in whatever IDE suite they are most comfortable with ultimately productivity will be the deciding factor. If engineer's are spending too much time converting project files back and forth between IDE's, well then having a standardized suite of software is probably the wise choice.

Answer (score 1):

to convert visual studio 2010 solution file (.sln) to visual studio 2008 solution file (.sln) simply follow these steps:

1. in .sln file replace "Format Version 11.00" to "Format Version 10.00"
2. in .sln file replace "# Visual Studio 2010" to "# Visual Studio 2008"
3. in .csproj replace "ToolsVersion=''4.0''" to "ToolsVersion=''3.5''"
4. in .csproj replace "v10.0" to "v9.0"