# opening visual studio 2010 solution files in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

How would you open a Visual Studio 2010 .sln file in Visual Studio 2008?

Is it possible? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at these questions for information about how to convert the solution file between VS2008 and VS2010:

- [VS2010 possible to convert projects back to VS2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227679/vs2010-possible-to-convert-projects-back-to-vs2008)
- [VS2010 and VS2008 project compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916190/vs2010-and-vs2008-project-compatibility)

But keep in mind, that once you have used some of the .NET 4 features (while in VS 2010), you will not be able to continue working with that solution in VS2008, since it does not support .NET 4. On the other hand, when using VS2010, you can still target .NET 3.5 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think I need more information... but I will try it.

One option is to create a new project in VS 2008 and simply add the files to the project.

Other option is to edit the .sln file and replace* Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00.* with *Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00.*

The open the .csproj file and replace 

with

Comment: I've done just that before in order to load sample files from online tutorials written for VS2010.  They have always opened for me okay in VS2008.  The code also executed fine, but I could have been lucky in that they all used a common API.

Answer (score 1):

Open the solution file (.sln) with notepad and change 
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2010

to
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

## Visual Studio 2008

Then open the solution file from visual studio 2008